# Right column not getting the full height of wrapper div

Tags: jquery, html, css

https://jsfiddle.net/nhgy11wx/

I have a left column floating, a right column and a wrapper for these two. I have the textarea on the right column on auto height, but I have also tried 100% and it is not getting the full height of the wrapper div. The two buttons below it should be right aligned on the bottom of everything, that is why I put them outside the main wrapper, but they also show inside it.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<title>Settings</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/ui-darkness/jquery-ui.css">
<style>
#wrapper {
    width: 980px;
    height: auto;
}
#wrapper div {
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
td {
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}
#ot_col1 {
    width: 20%;
}
#opt_table {
    width: 100%;
}
#ret_table {
    width: 70%;
}
#rt_col1 {
    width: 70%
}
#kv_txt {
    width: 30%;
}
#vs_txt {
    width: 30%;
}
#hp_txt {
    width: 100%;
}
#ws_doc_txt {
    width: 100%;
}
#ws_end_txt {
    width: 100%;
}
#ws_ns_txt {
    width: 100%;
}
#ws_op_txt {
    width: 50%;
}
#ws_par_txt {
    width: 50%;
}
#ws_val_txt {
    width: 50%;
}
#left_col {
    float: left;
    width: 480px;
    padding: 0 0 0 0;
}
#right_col {
    margin: 0 0 0 500px;
    padding: 0 0 0 0;
    text-align: left;
}
textarea {
    resize:none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
#button1 {
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.greentxt {
    color: green;
}
.redtxt {
    color: red;
}
.vert_al {
    vertical-align:bottom;
}
#status {
    font-style:bold;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="left_col">
    <fieldset><legend>Connection pconfiguration</legend>
    <div>
        <label>
        <input type="radio" name="ws_type" value="WSDL" id="ws_type_0">WSDL</label>
        <label>
        <input type="radio" name="ws_type" value="NOWSDL" id="ws_type_1">Endpoint</label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <table id="opt_table">
            <tr id="ws_doc">
                <td><label for="ws_doc">Document:</label></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="ws_doc" id="ws_doc_txt">
            </tr>
            <tr id="ws_end">
                <td><label for="ws_end">Endpoint:</label></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="ws_end" id="ws_end_txt">
            </tr>
            <tr id="ws_ns">
                <td><label for="ws_ns">Namespace:</label></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="ws_ns" id="ws_ns_txt"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="ws_op">
                <td id="ot_col1"><label for="ws_op">Operation:</label></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="ws_op" id="ws_op_txt"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="ws_par">
                <td><label for="ws_par">Parameter:</label></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="ws_par" id="ws_par_txt"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="ws_val">
                <td><label for="ws_val">Value:</label></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="ws_val" id="ws_val_txt"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    </fieldset>
    <div>
        <input type="submit" name="test" value="Test" class="vert_al">
        <img class="vert_al" src="../Desktop/arrow_anim_left.gif" width="48" height="36" alt=""/>
        <img class="vert_al" src="../Desktop/arrow_anim_left.gif" width="48" height="36" alt=""/>
        <img class="vert_al" src="../Desktop/arrow_anim_left.gif" width="48" height="36" alt=""/>
        <img class="vert_al" src="../Desktop/arrow_anim_left.gif" width="48" height="36" alt=""/>
        <img class="vert_al" src="../Desktop/arrow_anim_left.gif" width="48" height="36" alt=""/>
        <img class="vert_al" src="../Desktop/arrow_anim_left.gif" width="48" height="36" alt=""/>
        <img class="vert_al" src="../Desktop/arrow_anim_left.gif" width="48" height="36" alt=""/>
    </div>
    <fieldset><legend>Return type</legend>
    <div>
        <label>
        <input type="radio" name="ret_type" value="STRING" id="ret_type_0">String</label>
        <label>
        <input type="radio" name="ret_type" value="LIST" id="ret_type_1">List</label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <table id="ret_table">
            <tr id="kv">
                <td id="rt_col1"><label for="kv">Key-value pair separator:</label></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="kv" id="kv_txt">
            </tr>
            <tr id="vs">
                <td><label for="vs">Value assignment symbol:</label></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="vs" id="vs_txt">
            </tr>
            <tr id="hp">
                <td><label for="hp">Hash path:</label></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="hp" id="hp_txt"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    </fieldset>
</div>

<div id="right_col"><span id="status">Status:</span><span id="err_resp"></span>
<div id="textarea1">
<textarea readonly="readonly" id="response"></textarea>
</div>
</div>
</div> <!--wrapper div-->
<script>
$(document).ready( function() {
    $("*").addClass("ui-corner-all ui-widget");
    $("input[type=submit]").button();
    $("#ws_type_0").prop('checked','checked');
    $("#ret_type_0").prop('checked','checked');
    $("#ws_end").hide();
    $("#ws_ns").hide();
    $("#hp").hide();
    $("input[name=ws_type]").on('change', function() {
        if($(this).val()=="NOWSDL") {
            $("#ws_end").show();
            $("#ws_ns").show();
            $("#ws_doc").hide();
        }
        else if($(this).val()=="WSDL") {
            $("#ws_end").hide();
            $("#ws_ns").hide();
            $("#ws_doc").show();
        }
    });
    $("input[name=ret_type]").on('change', function() {
        if($(this).val()=="LIST") {
            $("#kv").hide();
            $("#vs").hide();
            $("#hp").show();
        }
        else if($(this).val()=="STRING") {
            $("#kv").show();
            $("#vs").show();
            $("#hp").hide();
        }
    });
    var xmlstr = "";
    xmlstr = "<CelsiusToFahrenheitResponse>\n  <CelsiusToFahrenheitResult>77</CelsiusToFahrenheitResult>\n</CelsiusToFahrenheitResponse>";
    $("#response").text(xmlstr);
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

when you want to assign a percent `width or height` (i.e `100%`) on anything, the rule of thumb is that the parent of that needs to have a `width/height`.

This means you `html` tag, along with the `body` tag and all children need to have a `width/height` specified (whether its `%` or `px`) so that any child below can have a `height/width` with `percents`.

take a look at this example http://jsfiddle.net/936ud8n5/3/

in this fiddle, the div with id `one` is invisible, because I've given it 100% height but its parents (body and html) have no height specified. However, the div inside of `two` is showing up, because `two` has a height of `100px` so its child `div` has height `100%` but it shows up.

also, div are `block` level elements, so they automatically take up the full width of the parent container. In this case, they entire width of the screen that they are in so no need to specify a width

Answer (score 0):

You have to add jquery script to set the height of right textarea box

```
$('#textarea1').css('height',$('#left_col').height());
```

You have update right col class property in css :

```
#right_col {
    /*margin: 0 0 0 500px;*/
    padding: 0 0 0 0;
    text-align: left;
    float:left;
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry the jquery code will not work since I have hidden elements and it doesn't align correctly. And the css code messes up the width of the textarea.

Answer (score 0):

Your `#wrapper` div height has collapsed since you floated the `.left_col` child div element and removed it from the flow. The wrapper height now only extends to the bottom of your `.right_col` element causing the buttons to appear directly below `.right_col`. You can get around this by adding `display:table;` to `#wrapper` or using a clearfix (see snippet below).

**Clearfix:**

```
#wrapper:after {
    clear: both;
    content: "";
    display: table;
}
```

Snippet with clearfix.

```js
    $("*").addClass("ui-corner-all ui-widget");
 $("input[type=submit]").button();
 $("#ws_type_0").prop('checked','checked');
 $("#ret_type_0").prop('checked','checked');
 $("#ws_end").hide();
 $("#ws_ns").hide();
 $("#hp").hide();
 $("input[name=ws_type]").on('change', function() {
  if($(this).val()=="NOWSDL") {
            $("#ws_end").show();
            $("#ws_ns").show();
            $("#ws_doc").hide();
  }
  else if($(this).val()=="WSDL") {
            $("#ws_end").hide();
            $("#ws_ns").hide();
            $("#ws_doc").show();
  }
 });
 $("input[name=ret_type]").on('change', function() {
  if($(this).val()=="LIST") {
            $("#kv").hide();
            $("#vs").hide();
   $("#hp").show();
  }
  else if($(this).val()=="STRING") {
            $("#kv").show();
            $("#vs").show();
   $("#hp").hide();
  }
 });
 var xmlstr = "";
 xmlstr = "<CelsiusToFahrenheitResponse>\n  <CelsiusToFahrenheitResult>77</CelsiusToFahrenheitResult>\n</CelsiusToFahrenheitResponse>";
 $("#response").text(xmlstr);
```

```css
#wrapper {
 width: 980px;
 height: auto;
    /* You can use this too - display:table; */
}

/* Clearfix */
#wrapper:after {
    clear: both;
    content: "";
    display: table;
} 
#wrapper div {
 margin-top: 5px;
 margin-bottom: 5px;
}
#bottom {
    text-align: right;
}
td {
 padding-top: 5px;
 padding-bottom: 5px;
}
#ot_col1 {
 width: 20%;
}
#opt_table {
 width: 100%;
}
#ret_table {
 width: 70%;
}
#rt_col1 {
 width: 70%
}
#kv_txt {
 width: 30%;
}
#vs_txt {
 width: 30%;
}
#hp_txt {
 width: 100%;
}
#ws_doc_txt {
 width: 100%;
}
#ws_end_txt {
 width: 100%;
}
#ws_ns_txt {
 width: 100%;
}
#ws_op_txt {
 width: 50%;
}
#ws_par_txt {
 width: 50%;
}
#ws_val_txt {
 width: 50%;
}
#left_col {
 float: left;
 width: 480px;
 padding: 0 0 0 0;
}
#right_col {
 margin: 0 0 0 500px;
 padding: 0 0 0 0;
 text-align: left;
}
textarea {
 resize:none;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}
#button1 {
 margin-top: 20px;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.greentxt {
 color: green;
}
.redtxt {
 color: red;
}
.vert_al {
 vertical-align:bottom;
}
#status {
 font-style:bold;
}
```

```html
<title>Settings</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="left_col">
 <fieldset><legend>Connection pconfiguration</legend>
 <div>
  <label>
  <input type="radio" name="ws_type" value="WSDL" id="ws_type_0">WSDL</label>
  <label>
  <input type="radio" name="ws_type" value="NOWSDL" id="ws_type_1">Endpoint</label>
 </div>
    <div>
        <table id="opt_table">
            <tr id="ws_doc">
                <td><label for="ws_doc">Document:</label></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="ws_doc" id="ws_doc_txt">
            </tr>
            <tr id="ws_end">
                <td><label for="ws_end">Endpoint:</label></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="ws_end" id="ws_end_txt">
            </tr>
            <tr id="ws_ns">
                <td><label for="ws_ns">Namespace:</label></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="ws_ns" id="ws_ns_txt"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="ws_op">
                <td id="ot_col1"><label for="ws_op">Operation:</label></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="ws_op" id="ws_op_txt"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="ws_par">
                <td><label for="ws_par">Parameter:</label></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="ws_par" id="ws_par_txt"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="ws_val">
                <td><label for="ws_val">Value:</label></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="ws_val" id="ws_val_txt"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
 </div>
    </fieldset>
 <div>
        <input type="submit" name="test" value="Test" class="vert_al">
        <img class="vert_al" src="../Desktop/arrow_anim_left.gif" width="48" height="36" alt=""/>
        <img class="vert_al" src="../Desktop/arrow_anim_left.gif" width="48" height="36" alt=""/>
        <img class="vert_al" src="../Desktop/arrow_anim_left.gif" width="48" height="36" alt=""/>
        <img class="vert_al" src="../Desktop/arrow_anim_left.gif" width="48" height="36" alt=""/>
        <img class="vert_al" src="../Desktop/arrow_anim_left.gif" width="48" height="36" alt=""/>
        <img class="vert_al" src="../Desktop/arrow_anim_left.gif" width="48" height="36" alt=""/>
        <img class="vert_al" src="../Desktop/arrow_anim_left.gif" width="48" height="36" alt=""/>
    </div>
    <fieldset><legend>Return type</legend>
 <div>
  <label>
  <input type="radio" name="ret_type" value="STRING" id="ret_type_0">String</label>
  <label>
  <input type="radio" name="ret_type" value="LIST" id="ret_type_1">List</label>
 </div>
    <div>
        <table id="ret_table">
            <tr id="kv">
                <td id="rt_col1"><label for="kv">Key-value pair separator:</label></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="kv" id="kv_txt">
            </tr>
            <tr id="vs">
                <td><label for="vs">Value assignment symbol:</label></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="vs" id="vs_txt">
            </tr>
            <tr id="hp">
                <td><label for="hp">Hash path:</label></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="hp" id="hp_txt"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
 </div>
    </fieldset>
</div>

<div id="right_col"><span id="status">Status:</span><span id="err_resp"></span>
<div id="textarea1">
<textarea readonly="readonly" id="response"></textarea>
</div> <!--textarea-->
</div> <!--right column-->
</div> <!--wrapper div-->
    <div id="bottom">
<input type="submit" name="Save" value="Save&Close"><input type="submit" name="Cancel" value="Cancel">
    </div>
```

Comment: adding either of those css fixes fixes nothing, checked both in dreamweaver and inside the snippet here. textarea still is not the same height as the left column and the bottom right buttons are all over the place too.

Comment: Then you will also have to specify a height on the parent element as Abdul Ahmad states in his answer.